# SQL Existing Column Conditional Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this data

```
AnsID  QuesID  AnsOrder
-----------------------
1       5       NULL
2       5       NULL
3       5       NULL
4       5       NULL
5       5       NULL
6       3       NULL
7       3       NULL
8       3       NULL
9       3       NULL
10      3       NULL
11      4       NULL
12      4       NULL
13      4       NULL
14      4       NULL
15      4       NULL
16      7       NULL
17      9       NULL
18      9       NULL
19      9       NULL
20      9       NULL
21      8       NULL
22      8       NULL
23      8       NULL
24      8       NULL
```

Want to UPDATE it into this format

```
AnsID  QuesID  AnsOrder
-----------------------

1       5       1
2       5       2
3       5       3
4       5       4    
5       5       5
6       3       1
7       3       2
8       3       3
9       3       4
10      3       5
11      4       1
12      4       2
13      4       3
14      4       4
15      4       5
16      7       1
17      9       1
18      9       2
19      9       3
20      9       4
21      8       1
22      8       2
23      8       3
24      8       4
```

Basicaly I want to update AnsOrder column in ascending order according to QuesID column,
like this for more readability.

```
AnsID  QuesID  AnsOrder
-----------------------

1       5       1
2       5       2
3       5       3
4       5       4    
5       5       5

6       3       1
7       3       2
8       3       3
9       3       4
10      3       5

11      4       1
12      4       2
13      4       3
14      4       4
15      4       5

16      7       1

17      9       1
18      9       2
19      9       3
20      9       4

21      8       1
22      8       2
23      8       3
24      8       4
```

Comment: How are you establishing the order to be assigned - there's no column to order by to generate the numeric indexing? (In the first few QuesIDs its in AnsID order, by the last couple are out of order.)

Comment: There needs to be another column, or an explanation, for why Question 9's Answers {11,25,23,13} receive the numbers {1,2,3,4} respectively (and similarly for other rows where the order doesn't seem to correspond to the numeric sequence for the answer IDs). Tables have no inherent order.

Comment: @JonEgerton Are you asking about any Primary key column here with unique IDs ??

Comment: You have manually applied an order to your data. I'm trying to establish the basis by which you decided what that ordering was, as that is what you need to recreate through SQL.

Comment: We are asking, what determines the order of AnsId for QuesId 8 and 9?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, What we have here is 6 unique QuesIDs i.e {5,3,4,7,9,8} now I want there AnsOrder to be in ascending order from 1-n according to number of QuesIDs so Frankly speaking AnsID doesn't have any role here, that's my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might generate row_numbers by quesID and assign them to AnsOrder like this:

```
; with ord as (
  select *,
         row_number() over (partition by quesID
                            order by AnsID) rn
    from table1
)
update ord 
   set ansorder = rn
```

I've ordered by AnsID for consistency.
[Check this @ Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30cdd/5).

Comment: Thanx dude, your solution was bang on... :)